# UIWebView loading html5-Video EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, exc-bad-access, html5-video

in our iPad-App we are using an UIWebView to load different sites from one domain some of them with a hml5-Video.
Sites without a Video do load perfectly. But when I'm loading a site containing htmlt5-video sometimes my app 
crashes during the loading-process of the UIWebView with EXC_BAD_ACCESS and sometimes it does not. Whenever such a crash occurs it seems to happen at the point where the Video-Player is added into the site.

I did download the UICatalog-Example from Apple and just did change the Default-URL in the WebViewController-Class to a URL of a site containg html5-video. Same results ... sometimes crash sometimes no crash.

I also did create a New Project on Xcode (View-based Application - for iPad) and only did add a UIWebView to the new Projects ViewController. Again ... loading a site containing html5-video sometimes leads to a crash and sometimes not.

CODE FROM "NEW PROJECTS" VIEWCONTROLLER (IMPLEMENTATION):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.myWebView = [[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1004)] autorelease];
    self.myWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.myWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    self.myWebView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
    self.myWebView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview: self.myWebView];

    [self.myWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.gelbeseiten.de/129103114849"]]];

    //More Sites with HTML5-Videos ...
    //[self.myWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.gelbeseiten.de/129103746403"]]];
    //[self.myWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.gelbeseiten.de/129105233646"]]];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];

    self.myWebView = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.myWebView stopLoading];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    myWebView.delegate = nil;
    [myWebView release];

    [super dealloc];
}
```

CODE FROM "NEW PROJECTS" VIEWCONTROLLER (HEADER):

```
@interface WebViewTestViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate> {
    UIWebView *myWebView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWebView *myWebView;
```

DEVICE LOGS:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00000098
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   WebCore                         0x34c7d09e WebCore::RenderLayer::clippingRoot() const + 110
1   WebCore                         0x34c7cf2a WebCore::RenderLayer::childrenClipRect() const + 26
2   WebCore                         0x34c7ce0c WebCore::RenderWidget::setWidgetGeometry(WebCore::IntRect const&) + 40
3   WebCore                         0x34c5e0f8 WebCore::RenderWidget::updateWidgetPosition() + 320
4   WebCore                         0x34ba0170 WebCore::RenderView::updateWidgetPositions() + 144
5   WebCore                         0x34b97d16 WebCore::FrameView::performPostLayoutTasks() + 202
6   WebCore                         0x34b8a6c0 WebCore::FrameView::layout(bool) + 2116
7   WebCore                         0x34bc5244 WebCore::FrameView::forceLayout(bool) + 4
8   WebKit                          0x302c0c24 -[WebHTMLView layoutToMinimumPageWidth:height:maximumPageWidth:adjustingViewSize:] + 136
9   WebKit                          0x302c0b8e -[WebHTMLView layout] + 18
10  WebKit                          0x302c26f2 -[WebHTMLView(WebInternal) _layoutIfNeeded] + 50
11  WebKit                          0x302c2622 -[WebHTMLView(WebInternal) _web_layoutIfNeededRecursive] + 14
12  WebKit                          0x302c251e -[WebHTMLView(WebPrivate) viewWillDraw] + 50
13  CoreFoundation                  0x3581dfc0 -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:] + 12
14  CoreFoundation                  0x35826d4a -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 382
15  WebCore                         0x34bb000c -[WAKView viewWillDraw] + 24
16  CoreFoundation                  0x3581dfc0 -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:] + 12
17  CoreFoundation                  0x35826d4a -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 382
18  WebCore                         0x34bb000c -[WAKView viewWillDraw] + 24
19  CoreFoundation                  0x3581dfc0 -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:] + 12
20  CoreFoundation                  0x35826d4a -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 382
21  WebCore                         0x34bb000c -[WAKView viewWillDraw] + 24
22  CoreFoundation                  0x3581dfc0 -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:] + 12
23  CoreFoundation                  0x35826d4a -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 382
24  WebCore                         0x34bb000c -[WAKView viewWillDraw] + 24
25  WebKit                          0x302c24cc -[WebView(WebPrivate) viewWillDraw] + 56
26  WebCore                         0x34bafec0 WebCore::TileCache::prepareToDraw() + 36
27  WebCore                         0x34bafe6e -[TileLayer display] + 26
28  QuartzCore                      0x31079fb0 CALayerDisplayIfNeeded + 176
29  QuartzCore                      0x3106f56e CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 214
30  QuartzCore                      0x3106f37c CA::Transaction::commit() + 184
31  QuartzCore                      0x31092f96 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 46
32  CoreFoundation                  0x3580ac52 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 10
33  CoreFoundation                  0x3580aac6 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 406
34  CoreFoundation                  0x358020c4 __CFRunLoopRun + 848
35  CoreFoundation                  0x35801c80 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
36  CoreFoundation                  0x35801b88 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
37  GraphicsServices                0x320c84a4 GSEventRunModal + 108
38  GraphicsServices                0x320c8550 GSEventRun + 56
39  UIKit                           0x341dc322 -[UIApplication _run] + 406
40  UIKit                           0x341d9e8c UIApplicationMain + 664
41  WebViewTest                     0x00002c24 0x1000 + 7204
42  WebViewTest                     0x00002bd8 0x1000 + 7128
```

Can anybody give me an idea?

Thanks in advance, Florian

Answer (score 2):

There is a little trick to override this crash. If you slightly scroll the webview just before the video content is loaded, the crash can be avoided. Before trying it out from code, try scrolling the webView a bit on device with your finger. It won't crash now.

In code, do something like this:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
  [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.scrollTo(0, 10);"];
}
```

to simulate a scroll on the webview through javascript. The scroll value can be as low as 1, so the user won't notice the scroll at all.

Answer (score 1):

Telling the webview to evaluate any JavaScript (or none at all) on webViewDidFinishLoad: seems work (albeit hacky).

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
  [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@""];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems I've solved this issue...
i've moved all HTML-5 video tags insertion in Javascript

```
function placeVideoTag() {
   var val = '<video />';
   var el = document.getElementById('video-id');
   el.innerHTML = val;
}
```

And i'm calling JS in **[UIWebView didFinishLoad]**

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)aWebView {
   [aWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"placeVideoTag()"];
}
```

Works perfectly in my case.
Other suggestions didn't work for me.

Comment: This solved the same problem for me on iOS 8.1.3!!! Adding video tag crashed my app, now i simply call the placeVideoTag and app doesn't crash anymore!!! Can believe this kind of regression. All my problems were identical to this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26656342/uiwebview-random-crash-at-uiviewanimationstate-release-message-sent-to-deallo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26656342/uiwebview-random-crash-at-uiviewanimationstate-release-message-sent-to-deallo)

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem. no answer yet. Saw many others reports similar problems - iOS 4.2.1 only.

Basically, I have a UIView Controller with a webview as its subview, and load a URLRequest to a youtube link.

The first time I load the viewController, the console logs error "Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols/System/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/QuickTime Plugin.webplugin/QuickTime Plugin (file not found).". I stop loading and release the viewController. The second time I re-load new viewController with the same request to that youtube link, now the app crashed with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: It really seems to be a problem with iOS 4.2.1. Tests with iOS 3.2.2 do not give a problem. Just read a Release-Note for next iOS 4.3: "Web - Fixed issue that caused Safari and other apps to crash after loading certain heavy Websites." Probably the Problem is solved with iOS 4.3

Comment: @Florian you are right! Problem solved by upgrading to Xcode 3.2.6 for iOS 4.3. I've postponed the app upgrade for two weeks just to wait for this...

Comment: Oh, my mistake, it wasn't solved in Xcode 3.2.6 for iOS 4.3 ... just because I was too excited to drag it before loaded, as suggested by Srijith Vijayamohan. I finally settled the problem via Srijith Vijayamohan's suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, for your posts!!! In my case it only works with different quite high offset-values for Portrait- and Landscape-Mode on iPad

(Portrait-Mode: greater than 60; Landscape-Mode: greater than 780):

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    if (self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||
    self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {

        [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.scrollTo(0, 60);"];
    } else if (self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
           self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {

        [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.scrollTo(0, 780);"];
    }
    webView.loadCounter--;
}
```

But with this solution my app crashes by double-tapping to zoom during the loading-process of a site.

I did subclass UIWebView to solve this problem (to prevent webView from zooming while loading):

```
.m:

@synthesize loadCounter;

- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint p = currentPoint;
    NSTimeInterval t = currentTimestamp;
    currentPoint = point;
    currentTimestamp = [event timestamp];

    if (CGPointEqualToPoint(p, point) &&
        [event timestamp] - t < 0.2 && loadCounter > 0){
        return self.superview;
    }

    return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}

.h:

@interface NonDoubleTapableWhileLoadingWebView : UIWebView {
    CGPoint currentPoint;
    NSTimeInterval currentTimestamp;

    NSInteger loadCounter;
}

@property (assign) NSInteger loadCounter;
```

And added a counter to determine the last "didFinish"-call and to reactivate the double-tapping possibility
(init loadCounter with 0)

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    linkWebView.loadCounter++;
}
```