# CA::release_objects(X::List<void const*>*)

Tags: c++

My app always get this error, most on iOS8, I cannot find reason, could anyone help me ?

```
    Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x36001f46 objc_msgSend + 5
1  CoreFoundation                 0x286f4e5d CFRelease + 600
2  QuartzCore                     0x2b6d1a65 CA::release_objects(X::List<void const*>*) + 16
3  QuartzCore                     0x2b6d1325 CA::Layer::~Layer() + 236
4  QuartzCore                     0x2b6d101d -[CALayer dealloc] + 64
5  QuartzCore                     0x2b6d0e1d CA::Layer::free_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 136
6  QuartzCore                     0x2b6cdab3 CA::Transaction::commit() + 418
7  QuartzCore                     0x2b6c792d CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 56
8  CoreFoundation                 0x287b43b5 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
9  CoreFoundation                 0x287b1a73 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 278
10 CoreFoundation                 0x287b1e7b __CFRunLoopRun + 914
11 CoreFoundation                 0x28700211 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 476
12 CoreFoundation                 0x28700023 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
13 GraphicsServices               0x2fab30a9 GSEventRunModal + 136
14 UIKit                          0x2bd0c1d1 UIApplicationMain + 1440
15 StockRadar                     0x00040a6f main (main.m:16)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are not using Animation you can avoid this bug by calling

```
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
```

In the init function of your controller. It appears to be a static class method so use verbatim.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, for me the problem is that my bug tracker track this bug wrong.

The real bug is this:

`*** -[UIViewAnimationState release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1c4c5ab0`

I'm following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26656342/uiwebview-random-crash-at-uiviewanimationstate-release-message-sent-to-deallo)

hope this can help you.