# WebCore crash log

Tags: ios, uiwebview, crash-log

rarely reproducible crash, which happens mostly if I leave app in background for a while and return foreground.
As far as I can see - crash is related to `UIWebView`, but not really clear it's nature. I don't use any animation.

Has somebody ever met something like this?

I've found similar post here:
[UIWebView random crash at [UIViewAnimationState release]: message sent to deallocated instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26656342/uiwebview-random-crash-at-uiviewanimationstate-release-message-sent-to-deallo)

iPhone 4s iOS 8.1

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3128d518 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3128d30c mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x233a6ba6 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 142
3   CoreFoundation                  0x233a516c __CFRunLoopRun + 1012
4   CoreFoundation                  0x232f297c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 472
5   CoreFoundation                  0x232f278e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   GraphicsServices                0x2a6cb04c GSEventRunModal + 132
7   UIKit                           0x268e497c UIApplicationMain + 1436
8   Demo                            0x00034f44 main (main.m:15)
9   libdyld.dylib                   0x311dbaac start + 0

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3128d2c8 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x311afe44 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 276
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x311afb76 _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$mp + 34

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x312a19cc __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3131de9c _pthread_wqthread + 788
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3131db74 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x312a19cc __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3131de9c _pthread_wqthread + 788
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3131db74 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x312a19cc __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3131de9c _pthread_wqthread + 788
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3131db74 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 5 name:  WebThread
Thread 5 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x30c4bf66 objc_msgSend + 6
1   CoreFoundation                  0x232e665c CFRelease + 592
2   QuartzCore                      0x262acfc0 CA::release_objects(X::List<void const*>*) + 12
3   QuartzCore                      0x262b22fe -[CAAnimation dealloc] + 50
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x30c59d52 objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) + 162
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x30c5a1a4 (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 400
6   CoreFoundation                  0x232f2704 _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 12
7   Foundation                      0x24033e0a -[NSAutoreleasePool drain] + 118
8   CFNetwork                       0x22f07944 AutoAutoreleasePool::~AutoAutoreleasePool() + 20
9   CFNetwork                       0x22eeb928 ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic18_withDelegateAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvP16_CFURLConnectionPK33CFURLConnectionClientCurrent_VMaxE_block_invoke_2 + 160
10  CFNetwork                       0x22e40186 RunloopBlockContext::_invoke_block(void const*, void*) + 58
11  CoreFoundation                  0x232f23ee CFArrayApplyFunction + 34
12  CFNetwork                       0x22e4003e RunloopBlockContext::perform() + 178
13  CFNetwork                       0x22e3ff06 MultiplexerSource::perform() + 214
14  CFNetwork                       0x22e3fda0 MultiplexerSource::_perform(void*) + 44
15  CoreFoundation                  0x233a75e4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 12
16  CoreFoundation                  0x233a69f6 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 218
17  CoreFoundation                  0x233a5074 __CFRunLoopRun + 764
18  CoreFoundation                  0x232f297c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 472
19  CoreFoundation                  0x232f278e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
20  WebCore                         0x2e6ae24c RunWebThread(void*) + 412
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3131fe64 _pthread_body + 136
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3131fdd6 _pthread_start + 114
23  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3131db80 thread_start + 4

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x312a19cc __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3131de9c _pthread_wqthread + 788
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3131db74 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x312a19cc __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3131de9c _pthread_wqthread + 788
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3131db74 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 8 name:  JavaScriptCore::BlockFree
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x312a0b38 __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3131f3dc _pthread_cond_wait + 516
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x313202ec pthread_cond_timedwait + 40
3   libc++.1.dylib                  0x30407074 std::__1::condition_variable::__do_timed_wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&, std::__1::chrono::time_point<std::__1::chrono::system_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1ll, 1000000000ll> > >) + 180
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x246d87ec std::__1::cv_status std::__1::condition_variable::wait_for<long long, std::__1::ratio<1ll, 1000ll> >(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1ll, 1000ll> > const&) + 196
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x245b3f16 JSC::BlockAllocator::blockFreeingThreadMain() + 82
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x245b044c WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 12
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3131fe64 _pthread_body + 136
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3131fdd6 _pthread_start + 114
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3131db80 thread_start + 4

Thread 9 name:  JavaScriptCore::Marking
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x312a0b38 __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3131f3dc _pthread_cond_wait + 516
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x313202ac pthread_cond_wait + 36
3   libc++.1.dylib                  0x30406fa4 std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 32
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x24778b60 JSC::GCThread::waitForNextPhase() + 100
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x24778bc4 JSC::GCThread::gcThreadMain() + 48
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x245b044c WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 12
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3131fe64 _pthread_body + 136
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3131fdd6 _pthread_start + 114
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3131db80 thread_start + 4

Thread 10 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3128d518 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3128d30c mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x233a6ba6 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 142
3   CoreFoundation                  0x233a516c __CFRunLoopRun + 1012
4   CoreFoundation                  0x232f297c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 472
5   CoreFoundation                  0x232f278e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   CFNetwork                       0x22ea79da +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 482
7   Foundation                      0x240f2996 __NSThread__main__ + 1114
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3131fe64 _pthread_body + 136
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3131fdd6 _pthread_start + 114
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3131db80 thread_start + 4

Thread 11 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x312a108c __select + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x233ab32e __CFSocketManager + 486
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3131fe64 _pthread_body + 136
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3131fdd6 _pthread_start + 114
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3131db80 thread_start + 4

Thread 12 name:  WebCore: CFNetwork Loader
Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3128d518 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3128d30c mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x233a6ba6 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 142
3   CoreFoundation                  0x233a516c __CFRunLoopRun + 1012
4   CoreFoundation                  0x232f297c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 472
5   CoreFoundation                  0x232f278e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   WebCore                         0x2e6d7558 WebCore::runLoaderThread(void*) + 288
7   JavaScriptCore                  0x245b044c WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 12
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3131fe64 _pthread_body + 136
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3131fdd6 _pthread_start + 114
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3131db80 thread_start + 4

Thread 13 name:  com.apple.coremedia.player.async
Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3128d568 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x311ad4e6 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 186
2   MediaToolbox                    0x24da843e fpa_AsyncMovieControlThread + 1962
3   CoreMedia                       0x23b4ce74 figThreadMain + 184
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3131fe64 _pthread_body + 136
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3131fdd6 _pthread_start + 114
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3131db80 thread_start + 4

Thread 14 name:  AVAudioSession Notify Thread
Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3128d518 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3128d30c mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x233a6ba6 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 142
3   CoreFoundation                  0x233a516c __CFRunLoopRun + 1012
4   CoreFoundation                  0x232f297c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 472
5   CoreFoundation                  0x232f278e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   libAVFAudio.dylib               0x220163e8 GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 128
7   libAVFAudio.dylib               0x220088e4 CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 192
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3131fe64 _pthread_body + 136
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3131fdd6 _pthread_start + 114
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3131db80 thread_start + 4

Thread 5 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x14591630    r1: 0x2dc13dbd      r2: 0x315aff18      r3: 0xeb959ea0
    r4: 0x61459630    r5: 0x14591634      r6: 0x14591630      r7: 0x029e2bec
    r8: 0x315a8b2c    r9: 0x81459318     r10: 0x3395a600     r11: 0x3395a980
    ip: 0x315847f4    sp: 0x029e2ba4      lr: 0x232e6661      pc: 0x30c4bf66
  cpsr: 0x70000030
```