# Sencha Touch + phonegap app crashing on ios 8

Tags: cordova, ios8, sencha-touch-2.3

I am using sencha touch 2.3.1 and phonegap to make an app. my app is crashing on ios8. Everytime I open the app in iOS 8 it shows a black screen after splash screen and then app crashes. But when I open **recent apps** the app is still there in the list. Sometimes it opens app when I keep pressing app icon form menu.

The same app is working fine on iOS 7.

I have researched about this issue everywhere, some people say that Phonegap is not fully supporting iOS 8 and some of the plugins are not updated yet for iOS 8. some people say Sencha Touch 2 is also not supporting iOS 8.

here is the list phonegap plugins that i am using in the app:

```
com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin
org.apache.cordova.device
org.apache.cordova.dialogs
org.apache.cordova.file
org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser
org.apache.cordova.media
org.apache.cordova.network-information
```

Please help me with this issue.

here is my crash log. it is throwing an Exception : EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)

```
Incident Identifier: D57CDEC3-6F31-40D0-84E8-DBAFD61B015F
CrashReporter Key:   6ab1cf64690b5804d92476585fb118afc35b9a26
Hardware Model:      iPhone4,1
Process:             xyz [1163]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/F81EF27D-391D-43F9-9162-B9AB6A55A5F9/xyz.app/xyz
Identifier:          abc
Version:             1.0.6 (1.0.6)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-06-03 14:25:15.200 +0530
Launch Time:         2015-06-03 14:25:12.754 +0530
OS Version:          iOS 8.3 (12F70)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x214d502a
Triggered by Thread:  8

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31c8649c mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31c86290 mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x235607ee __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 142
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2355edb4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1012
4   CoreFoundation                  0x234aa99c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 472
5   CoreFoundation                  0x234aa7ae CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   GraphicsServices                0x2ac831a4 GSEventRunModal + 132
7   UIKit                           0x26c35690 UIApplicationMain + 1436
8   HireStorm                       0x000ae73e main (main.m:32)
9   libdyld.dylib                   0x31bd3aac start + 0

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31c8624c kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x31ba64ec _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 276
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x31ba621e _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$mp + 34

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31c9a9c0 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x31d17e20 _pthread_wqthread + 788
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x31d17af8 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31c9a9c0 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x31d17e20 _pthread_wqthread + 788
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x31d17af8 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31c9a9c0 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x31d17e20 _pthread_wqthread + 788
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x31d17af8 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31c9a9c0 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x31d17e20 _pthread_wqthread + 788
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x31d17af8 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 6 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31c8649c mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31c86290 mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x235607ee __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 142
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2355edb4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1012
4   CoreFoundation                  0x234aa99c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 472
5   CoreFoundation                  0x234aa7ae CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   CFNetwork                       0x23048642 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 482
7   Foundation                      0x242d9186 __NSThread__main__ + 1114
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x31d19de8 _pthread_body + 136
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x31d19d5a _pthread_start + 114
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x31d17b04 thread_start + 4

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31c9a9c0 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x31d17e20 _pthread_wqthread + 788
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x31d17af8 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 8 name:  WebThread
Thread 8 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x31637f66 objc_msgSend + 6
1   CoreFoundation                  0x2349e67c CFRelease + 592
2   QuartzCore                      0x265f0450 CA::release_objects(X::List<void const*>*) + 12
3   QuartzCore                      0x265f5b30 -[CAAnimation dealloc] + 52
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x31645d52 objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) + 162
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x316461a4 (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 400
6   CoreFoundation                  0x234aa724 _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 12
7   Foundation                      0x2421a27a -[NSAutoreleasePool drain] + 118
8   CFNetwork                       0x230a933c AutoAutoreleasePool::~AutoAutoreleasePool() + 20
9   CFNetwork                       0x2308d020 ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic18_withDelegateAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvP16_CFURLConnectionPK33CFURLConnectionClientCurrent_VMaxE_block_invoke_2 + 160
10  CFNetwork                       0x22fe08d6 RunloopBlockContext::_invoke_block(void const*, void*) + 58
11  CoreFoundation                  0x234aa40e CFArrayApplyFunction + 34
12  CFNetwork                       0x22fe078e RunloopBlockContext::perform() + 178
13  CFNetwork                       0x22fe0656 MultiplexerSource::perform() + 214
14  CFNetwork                       0x22fe04f0 MultiplexerSource::_perform(void*) + 44
15  CoreFoundation                  0x2356122c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 12
16  CoreFoundation                  0x2356063e __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 218
17  CoreFoundation                  0x2355ecbc __CFRunLoopRun + 764
18  CoreFoundation                  0x234aa99c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 472
19  CoreFoundation                  0x234aa7ae CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
20  WebCore                         0x2ef3650c RunWebThread(void*) + 412
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x31d19de8 _pthread_body + 136
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x31d19d5a _pthread_start + 114
23  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x31d17b04 thread_start + 4

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31c9a9c0 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x31d17e20 _pthread_wqthread + 788
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x31d17af8 start_wqthread + 4
```

Comment: My app used to crash due to the last version of a few plugins. I've downgraded some of them and it worked back.. just saying, if it may help

Comment: I occasionally see this crash in my app a minority of the time. it seems like it's an iOS bug, as indicated here and here:
https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=138961
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26656342/uiwebview-random-crash-at-uiviewanimationstate-release-message-sent-to-deallo

Answer (score 0):

The crash log will help identify the reason for the crash.

1. Connect your device to your Mac.
2. In Xcode, select **Window**, then **Devices** (or press ⇧⌘2).
3. Select your device and click **View Device Logs**.
4. Select the crash log you want to view.